# warning: passing argument 1 of ‘word_search’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

Tags: c, string, function, pointers

I'm pretty new to C programming and I keep getting these errors that I have no clue of:

```
HW5_mkhan44.c: In function ‘main’:
HW5_mkhan44.c:31:3: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘word_search’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
HW5_mkhan44.c:9:5: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘struct FILE **’
HW5_mkhan44.c:31:3: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘word_search’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
HW5_mkhan44.c:9:5: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
HW5_mkhan44.c:31:3: error: too many arguments to function ‘word_search’
HW5_mkhan44.c:9:5: note: declared here
```

Also, here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int word_search(char word[100], char str[100]);
int character_count(char curr_str[100]);
void search_count(FILE *fpter, char c[100], int *len, int *result);

int main(void)
{
        FILE *fileptr;
        char filename[100];
        char* word[100];
        int *length;
        int *num;

        printf("Please input the text file name: ");
        scanf("%s", filename);

        fileptr = fopen(filename, "r");



    if(fileptr == NULL)
                printf("File does not exist");
        else{
                printf("Please enter a word to search: ");
                scanf("%s", word);
                word_search(&fileptr, word, &length, &num);

                if(*num == 0){  
                        printf("Word exists in file");
                        printf("There are %d characters in file", *length);
                }
                else
                        printf("Word does not exist in file");
        }
        fclose(fileptr);

        return 0;
}

int word_search(char word[100], char str[100])
{
        int num;
        if(strcmp(word, str) == 0){
                num = 0;
                return(num);
        }
        else{
                num = 1;
                return(num);
        }
}

int character_count(char current_str[100])
{
        int word_length;

        word_length = strlen(current_str);

        return(word_length);
}

void search_and_count(FILE *fpter, char c[100], int *len, int *result)
{
        char line[120];

        while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fpter)){
                char* t = strtok(line, " ");
                *len = wordsearch(c, t);
                *result = character_count(t);
        }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I know you are new to C. But it seems you have basic errors that even a novice can see if you actually reviewed your code carefully. For example, `int word_search(char word[100], char str[100]);` declares a function taking two parameters yet you call it with four parameters: `word_search(&fileptr, word, &length, &num);`.

Comment: And remove `*` from `char* word[100];
        int *length;
        int *num;`

Comment: when coding, indent consistently,  Do not use tabs for indenting.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}`.  Suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level.   Never use tabs because each word processor/editor has the tab stops/tab width set differently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wordsearh function is defined with 2 parameters:

```
int word_search(char word[100], char str[100])
```

And you are calling with 4 parameters;

```
word_search(&fileptr, word, &length, &num);
```

Don't you want to call function **search_and_count** from **main**?